# Modify the Geoserver REST response href values to use domain name instead of IP address

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

Currently, the Geoserver REST API responds with objects that look like such:

```
{
    "layers": {
        "layer": [
            {
                "name": "layername1",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/layername1.json"
            },
            {
                "name": "layername2",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/layername2.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can I configure geoserver to use a domain name for the href values like so:

```
{
    "layers": {
        "layer": [
            {
                "name": "layername1",
                "href": "http://example.domain.com/geoserver/rest/layers/layername1.json"
            },
            {
                "name": "layername2",
                "href": "http://example.domain.com/geoserver/rest/layers/layername2.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure the proxy base url setting: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#proxy-base-url